# Doctrine / Symfony model won't delete when instanciated with new

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony-1.4

A quick question, but does anyone know why the code below won't actually delete anything from my database? The `->delete()` returns `true`...

```
$model = new Model();
$model->setPrimaryKeyPart1($value1);
$model->setPrimaryKeyPart2($value2);
$model->delete(); // returns true, but isn't deleted.
```

Note that this model is a many to many table with all values being the primary key.

I have the feeling it has something to do with it having a `isNew` flag, is there any way to delete the model this way without having to query it from the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your object `$model` don't come from the database but is programmatically initialized.

Even if you set `PK1` and `PK2`. There is no database connection associated with the object.

It should be better to retrieve the object from the db and then delete it.

Comment: That is quite a shame, as I don't want to waste a select statement on the database for a delete statement I want executed. Thank you for your answer!